# How save the selectedOption from p:selectOneMenu with a ui:repeat. I am only getting the value of the last p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to save the selectedOption from `p:selectOneMenu` with a `ui:repeat`? I am only getting the value of the last  `p:selectOneMenu`

```
    <ui:repeat value="#{formFieldsBean.fieldList}" var="field">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid2"
            columnClasses="ui-grid-col-5,ui-grid-col-4"
            layout="grid"
            styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ui-fluid"
            style="border:0px none; background-color:transparent;">
                             
            <p:outputLabel  for="@next" value="#{field.question}" rendered="#{field.type == grp.grp}"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{formFieldsBean.selectedOption}"  rendered="#{field.type == grp.grp}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="NA" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: You cant do that.  All of your fields in the UI repeat point to the same backing bean value `#{formFieldsBean.selectedOption}`so it makes sense only the last value is being saved.  You need to store each one its its OWN value.

Comment: Melloware Thank You  let me try to store each one its Own value